# How to add spring property or environment variable in LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder?

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, logstash

I have the configuration below. However, I need to put an environment variable after the LogLevel as a specific field. I don't know if it makes it easier, but I have this environment variable mapped in the `application.properties` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
            <providers>
                <threadName />
                <logLevel />
                <loggerName>
                    <shortenedLoggerNameLength>36</shortenedLoggerNameLength>
                </loggerName>
                <arguments>
                    <includeNonStructuredArguments>false</includeNonStructuredArguments>
                </arguments>
                <stackTrace />
                <message />
            </providers>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I discover that I need to use the thag appender. Thank you...

```
    <configuration>
        <property resource="application.properties" />
        <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
            <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
                <providers>
                    <logLevel/>
                    <pattern>
                        <pattern>
                            {
                                "service": "${spring.application.name:-}",
                                "traceId": "%X{traceId:-}",
                                "spanId": "%X{spanId:-}",
                                "pid": "${PID:-}"
                            }
                        </pattern>
                    </pattern>
                    <threadName />
                    <loggerName>
                        <shortenedLoggerNameLength>36</shortenedLoggerNameLength>
                    </loggerName>
                    <arguments>
                        <includeNonStructuredArguments>false</includeNonStructuredArguments>
                    </arguments>
                    <stackTrace />
                    <message />
                </providers>
            </encoder>
        </appender>
        <root level="DEBUG">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        </root>
    </configuration>
```